# Reading information from the filename

Tags: r, filenames

I have the following character list:

```
$`1`
[1] "TEMP_sim_zone1_cell_1_5_"

$`5`
[1] "TEMP_sim_zone1_cell_1_5_"

$`6826`
[1] "TEMP_sim_zone338_cell_6826_"

$`9888`
[1] "TEMP_sim_zone615_cell_9888_9890_9895"

$`9890`
[1] "TEMP_sim_zone615_cell_9888_9890_9895"

$`9892`
[1] "TEMP_sim_zone614_cell_9892"

$`9895`
[1] "TEMP_sim_zone615_cell_9888_9890_9895"
```

From this, I want to create this matrix (nrow=7, ncol=2):

```
   1  1
   5  2
6826  1
9888  1
9890  2
9892  1
9895  3
```

For example, cells 9888, 9890 and 9895 should be read in file "TEMP_sim_zone615_cell_9888_9890_9895". 9888 is in position 1, 9890 in position 2 and 9895 in position 3 (this information should be taken from the position of the cells in the filename).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way, where `temp` is your list (simplified by @Thomas's advice)

```
temp2 <- mapply(match, names(temp), strsplit(gsub("^.*\\cell_", "", temp), "_"))
temp2 <- cbind(as.numeric(names(temp2)), as.numeric(temp2))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    5    2
# [3,] 6826    1
# [4,] 9888    1
# [5,] 9890    2
# [6,] 9892    1
# [7,] 9895    3
```

Comment: This can be simplified to just `mapply(match, names(temp), strsplit(gsub("^.*cell_", "", temp), "_"))` No need for extra `lapply` since `gsub` is vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get a named vector:

```
sapply(names(l), function(x) {
  s <- sub('.+_cell_', '', l[[x]])
  ids <- strsplit(s, '_', fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  which(ids == x)
})
#    1    5 6826 9888 9890 9892 9895 
#    1    2    1    1    2    1    3
```

Comment: +1, but to get the OP's requested matrix output format, change the return value to `c(as.numeric(x), which(ids == x))` and then wrap the `sapply` in `t()`.